# Undefined offset: 4 tried a lot of remedies

Tags: php, drupal, offset

```
function webform_registrationpw_submit($form, &$form_state) {
// first, we need to identify the password field for this registration form
$node = node_load($form_state['values']['details']['nid']);
$nodePassField = "";

  foreach( $node->webform['components'] as $key => $value ) {
    if ( $value['form_key'] =="password"  ) { 
      $nodePassField = $key;
    }
  }

  if ( "" == $form_state['values']['submitted'][$nodePassField] ) { //this is the line giving the error
    $form_state['values']['submitted'][$nodePassField] = newpw(8);  // set new password
  }
}
```

Hi everyone, above is the code that is giving me an "Undefined offset: 4" error. I have tried using isset() and a couple of other things and I continue to get the error. Could you help me out? I am still pretty new and learning.

Thanks.

Comment: `$nodePassField = 4;` What does the rest of $form_state look like?

Comment: Where does $nodePassField come from?

Comment: Troubleshooting tip: do a `print_r($_POST)` and see if you actually have the values.

Comment: do var_dump($form_state) to see what is its content. Seems that $nodePassField is taking value 4 which doesn't exists.

Comment: I will be doing your recommendations slowly and posting back here! Sorry, this is a new PHP app (Drupal) and I am learning it as I go.

Comment: I added more code, now I think I broke the function trying to fix the error. It no longer creates a new random password. Argh.

Comment: I did not break it, nevermind. But yes, that is the code I am trying to fix. It actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was some weird bug with the "if" looking for a null field. So deleted the if and modified the code to this:

```
function webform_registrationpw_submit($form, &$form_state) {
// first, we need to identify the password field for this registration form
$node = node_load($form_state['values']['details']['nid']);
$nodePassField = "";

  foreach( $node->webform['components'] as $key => $value ) {
    if ( $value['form_key'] =="password"  ) { 
      $nodePassField = $key;
    }
  }
  $form_state['values']['submitted'][$nodePassField] = newpw(8);  // set new password
}
```

Viola, works great!